# HTTPS Redirection using Web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I have a small demo application that I am trying to work on using web.py, to be hosted in Cloudfoundry, that will use the `seeother` function to redirect back to the home page after performing a certain operation in one of the Views.

However, the problem is when the `seeother` tries to return back to the home page, it uses the http url for redirection.

I forcefully don't want to code the https urls into the file and was wondering if there is an easy way to get around this problem ?

The `web.ctx.protocol` is returning http and so is `wsgi.url_scheme`

Answer (score 0):

SeeOther is permitted to use a relative URI (RFC 7231), so you could do something like:

```
raise web.seeother('https:/home.html')
```

to return to `home.html` of the current host, but forcing https.

Comment: This is something I don't really want to do. This works at a small scale when things are easy to manage, but with growing code, it becomes too messy to manage and track them.

Comment: I'm confused, then: to where do you want to redirect the user... Is it always to the same place, or different places based on (perhaps) current location? SeeOther must have a URL.

Comment: It might differ based on what Page I am at. But I want to use the relative URLs and not the Actual URLs for seeother Method.

Comment: Relative URI work, also: `web.seeother('../index.html')`, for example.